# Delete spaces and column in csv with powershell

Tags: file, csv, powershell, space

I'm trying to convert a downloaded ".txt" file into a goodlooking and useful ".csv" file using powershell. I'm kindly advanced with this task but shortly before the goal I have some problems which I can not manage.

It is a list with the OUI-Part of mac-addresses and its names.
This is how it looks like (without quotation):

```
" 00-00-00   "  EMPTY COLUMN    "XEROX CORPORATION"
" 00-00-01   "  EMPTY COLUMN    "XEROX CORPORATION"
```

My first question now is, how can I get the spaces in the column of the OUI-address away. The secound one, how can I delete the empty column.

In the end it should look like this (without quotation):

```
"00-00-00" "XEROX CORPORATION"
"00-00-01" "XEROX CORPORATION"
```

So that we have in the first column the OUI without any spaces and in the second column the name of the company. But here it is important to have spaces in the name.

Original file content:

```
  00-00-09          XEROX CORPORATION
  00-00-0A          OMRON TATEISI ELECTRONICS CO.
  00-00-0B          MATRIX CORPORATION
  00-00-0C          CISCO SYSTEMS, INC.
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please update your question with the literal content of the original text file. (It doesn't contain the strings "EMPTY COLUMN", does it?)

Comment: You are right it doesn't contain "EMPTY COLUMN". I will update the question. Thanks

Comment: You also mention MAC addresses, but MAC addresses have six pairs of digits, not three.

Comment: Yeah right excuse me thats only the first 24 bits so its the part to identify the organization (OUI (Organizationally Unique Identifier))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, using `Get-Content` and `Select-String` with a regular expression to extract the substrings:

```
get-content "test.txt" | foreach-object {
  $_ | select-string '\s*((?:[0-9a-f]{2}-){2}[0-9a-f]{2})\s+(.+)$' | foreach-object {
    $oui = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
    $description = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
  }
  new-object PSObject -property @{
    "OUI" = $oui
    "Description" = $description
  } | select-object OUI,Description
}
```

For output that contains pairs of quoted strings, replace `New-Object` with a formatted string; for example:

```
get-content "test.txt" | foreach-object {
  $_ | select-string '\s*((?:[0-9a-f]{2}-){2}[0-9a-f]{2})\s+(.+)$' | foreach-object {
    $oui = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
    $description = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
  }
  '"{0}" "{1}"' -f $oui,$description
}
```

You can use a regular expression tester such as https://www.regex101.com/ to see how the regular expression (i.e., the parameter to `Select-String`) extracts the substrings.

Comment: These expression testers are quite cool. I can check what each expression of your code does. I'm quite new to powershell how do I write the OUI and Description now line for line among themselves in a file?

Comment: Add `| export-csv "test.csv" -notypeinformation` after the closing `}` character on the last line of my example code. That will output the objects to a CSV file.

Comment: That works but now it is going to look like this:

`00-00-09,"XEROX CORPORATION"` 
`00-00-0A,"OMRON TATEISI ELECTRONICS CO."  `
`00-00-0B,"MATRIX CORPORATION" ` 

But it is not Tab Seperated and there are quotations

Comment: Looks better but when I use `'"{0}" "{1}"' -f $oui,$description`
and write it afterwards in the csv file using `| export-csv "test.csv" -notypeinformation` the file is going to look very weird `Length
30
30
30
30
`
Excuse me for my bad powershell skills and much thanks for your help

Comment: Do not use `Export-CSV` if you want to use the formatted string. Use `| out-file "newfile.txt"` instead. If you want a tab between the columns, the formatted string would be ``'"{0}"`t"{1}"' -f $oui,description`` (i.e., replace the space between with `\`t`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer is great. It is working like i visualised it. Thanks for your expenditure of time